# passing an object to a function is not resulting into a constructor call

Tags: c++, function, for-loop, constructor

Shouldnt there be a call to a constructor when I call f1 in the below code?
I see "this" pointer is different in the object b (param to f1) , which means a new object is created, but I dont see the print in the constructor for b.
But there is call to destructor, can anyone explain?

```
class A
{
    int k ;
public:
    A(int i)
    {
        k=i;
        printf("%d inside [%s]ptr[%p]\n",k,__FUNCTION__,this);
    }
    ~A()
    {
        printf("%d inside [%s]ptr[%p]\n",k,__FUNCTION__,this);
    }
    void A_fn()
    {
        printf("%d inside [%s]ptr[%p]\n",k,__FUNCTION__,this);
    }
};
void f1(A b)
{
    b.A_fn();
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A a(10);
    f1(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Output shown in vc++ 2012:

```
10 inside [A::A]ptr[00B3FBD0]

10 inside [A::A_fn]ptr[00B3FAEC]

10 inside [A::~A]ptr[00B3FAEC]

10 inside [A::~A]ptr[00B3FBD0]

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: add a comment in copy constructor and check...

Answer (score 2):

Because when you pass an object by value, the object is *copied* and therefore the copy-constructor will be called.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, you need to add a copy constructor to class A.  This is how it should look:

```
A(const A&)
{
    printf("Inside copy constructor\n");
}
```